# squeeze theorem vs. along different paths

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate $\lim _{(u, v) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{u v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{4}}$.
Firstly, I tried:
Along
$
u=m v^{2}, m \in \mathbb{R}
$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\lim _{(u, v) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{u v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{4}}=\lim _{\left(m v^{2}, v\right) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\left(m v^{2}\right) v^{2}}{\left(m v^{2}\right)^{2}+v^{4}} \\
=\lim _{\left(m v^{2}, v\right) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{m v^{4}}{m v^{4}+v^{4}} \\
=\lim _{\left(m v^{2}, v\right) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{m v^{4}}{m v^{4}+v^{4}} \\
=\lim _{\left(m v^{2}, v\right) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{m}{m+1}
\end{array}
$$
Thus the limit differs for different values of $m$ and so does not exist.
However, Using the sandwich/squeeze theorem, where
$$
\begin{array}{l}
-\frac{\left(u^{2}+v^{4}\right) v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{4}}=-v^{2} \leq \frac{u v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{4}} \leq \frac{\left(u^{2}+v^{4}\right) v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{4}}=v^{2} \\
\lim _{(u, v) \rightarrow(0,0)}-v^{2}=\lim _{(u, v) \rightarrow(0,0)} v^{2}=0 \\
\therefore \lim _{(u, v) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{u v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{4}}=0
\end{array}
$$
Am I using the sandwich theorem wrongly?

Basically I find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x^2y/(x^4 + y^2)$ to be different along different paths or $0$ using the sandwich theorem. Am I using the sandwich theorem wrongly? Please see the link for my workings. Help much appreciated!!

Comment: Used squeeze theorem incorrectly. The bounds are not correct. You can see this by letting $v = 0$. Then, if you let $u<0$ and arbitrarily close, then the inequalities do not hold.